# Electromagnetic waves produced from a sinusoidal current

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

Say I have an oscillating sinusoidal current flowing on the z-axis (say $I_0\sin{\omega t}$), in a straight line conductor. This current produces an alternating magnetic field in the azimuthal direction, which produces an changing electric field in the z direction, which creates an EM wave in the radial direction. How would one formally derive the expression for the induced magnetic and electric fields?

My initial response was that the magnetic field expression follows from the Ampere's Circuital law, i.e.

$$ B = \frac{\mu _o I_o \sin{\omega t}}{2\pi r} $$
in the azimuthal direction. However, this means ignoring the $\epsilon _o\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$ part from the Maxwell's extension that is responsible for EM waves in the first place.

I tried to derive the wave equation from Maxwell's laws, but since it is not in free space and there is non-zero current density, I got stuck at

$$ \nabla ^2\overrightarrow{E} = \mu_o\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial ^2 \overrightarrow{E}}{\partial t^2} + \mu_0 \frac{\partial\overrightarrow{J}}{\partial t}$$

Any help?

Comment: I presume you are talking about a long wire where you cannot use the oscillating electric dipole approximation? Otherwise this is discussed extensitvely in every textbook n electrodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

The current density is concentrated in the $z$-axis
$$\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t)=I_0 \mathbf{e}_z \delta(x)\delta(y) \sin(\omega t)$$
where $\mathbf{e}_z$ is the unit vector in $z$ direction
and $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
Of course it is advantageous to use cylindrical coordinates ($r,\phi,z$)
instead of cartesian ($x,y,z$).
$$\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t)=I_0 \mathbf{e}_z \frac{\delta(r)}{2\pi r} \sin(\omega t)$$

You will also need the charge density $\rho$ so that charge conservation
$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{J}+\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=0$
is satisfied. It is easy to check that $\rho=0$ satifies this.

Then it is straight forward to write down Maxwell's equations (including
Maxwell's extension $\epsilon_0\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$).
Look up the expressions for [divergence ($\nabla\cdot$) and
curl ($\nabla\times$) operators in cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Cylindrical_derivation),
work through the math, and get 8 differential equations for
$B_r,B_\phi,B_z,E_r,E_\phi,E_z$.

It is reasonable to expect only the components $B_\phi$ and $E_z$
to be non-zero, and furthermore not depending on $\phi$ and $z$.
Using this approach you will find many of your differential
equations are satisfied trivially.
And you will end up with only 2 differential equations,
for $B_\phi(r,t)$ and $E_z(r,t)$.
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial(rB_\phi)}{\partial r} = \mu_0\left(
J_z+\epsilon_0\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial t}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial B_\phi}{\partial t}$$

Because of the term $\epsilon_0\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$
you won't succeed with a magnetic field propagating with infinite speed like
$$B_\phi(r,t) = \frac{\mu _0 I_0}{2\pi r}\sin(\omega t).$$

A better guess is a magnetic and electric field propagating outwards
with the speed of light $c=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}$.
$$B_\phi(r,t) = \frac{\mu_0 I_0}{2\pi r}
\sin\left(\omega\left(t-\frac{r}{c}\right)\right)$$
$$E_z(r,t) = -\frac{c\mu_0 I_0}{2\pi r}
\sin\left(\omega\left(t-\frac{r}{c}\right)\right)$$
But unfortunately even this is only an approximate solution.
For an exact solution you need [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{J}$ is non-zero on the wire but zero everywhere else. So you have your wave equation.

To compute the fields, you can get them from retarded potentials:
$$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'},t_r)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}d\mathbf{r'}$$
$$V(\mathbf{r},t)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r'},t_r)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}d\mathbf{r'}$$
where $t_r\equiv t-|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|/c$ is the retarded time. Finally,
$$\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$$
$$\mathbf{E}=-\nabla V-\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t}$$